# Triple Des codes returning cipher with different lengths

Tags: java, c#, android, encryption, tripledes

I have got this code from Server guys:

```
public string Encryption(string PlainText)
{
string key = "twelve_digit_key";
TripleDES des = CreateDES(key);
ICryptoTransform ct = des.CreateEncryptor();
byte[] input = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(PlainText);
byte[] buffer = ct.TransformFinalBlock(input, 0, input.Length);

return Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
}

static TripleDES CreateDES(string key)
{
 MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
 TripleDES des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
 des.Key = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key));
 des.IV = new byte[des.BlockSize / 8];
 return des;
}
```

This is my code against above :

```
 public String encryptDES(String message) throws Exception {
    final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
    final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest(getNativeKey3().getBytes("utf-8"));
    final byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
    for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8; ) {
        keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
    }

    final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(digestOfPassword, "DESede");
    final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

    final byte[] plainTextBytes = message.getBytes("utf-8");
    final byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);

    return Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.DEFAULT)
        .replace("\n", "")
        .replace("\r", "");
}
```

**Problem :**

First Code gives below result :

- *Encrypted Text for 121212 is  **VvRQkSUj5SQ69mGXsL+h6w==***

But Second Code returns this :

- *Encrypted Text for 121212 is **2STVJSd1mnw=***

**Observations :**

- *When I increase the plainttext to 10 digits I am getting 24 digit cipher text*

Can any one help me in this:

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Needless to say, that code above from the "server guys" is utter trash. MD5 for password derivation, without indicating the input format, using 3DES, not specifying the protocol, using Unicode without reason, an all zero IV. WTF dudes...

Comment: I will tell them to improve their code, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've been fooled by the badly named [`Unicode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.unicode?view=netframework-4.7.2) class, which actually specifies UTF-16LE rather than UTF-8.

You can use [`StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_16LE) for specifying the encoding rather than the string; this saves you from one exception to handle.

If there are still issues with the length (test!) then you may have to deal with the Byte Order Mark or BOM - but I don't think so.